# Detect cause of FPS jolt - LIBGDX

Tags: java, performance, libgdx

I'm testing my game right now . I get constant 60-61 FPS with a few exceptions. Those exceptions I want to find the cause of. Is there a special debugger that can detect the method (function, event) which is sometimes causing the FPS drop from 60-61 to 58-59 FPS? I know it's not that of a big of difference but I get unpleasant results , weird jolts of sprites (I'm using framerate-independent movement). Weirdly enough this happens on the phone that is the most powerful from the lot of phones I'm testing the game on. Also, on the PC there is no frame drop.

Comment: Maybe this (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Profiling) could help?

Comment: Could it be the garbage collector? Make sure you don't allocate a lot of objects in the render loop.

Comment: If the garbage collector is the reason for the FPS drops, like @Tenfour04 mentioned, you could also consider using `Pool`s (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management#object-pooling).